# nginx regex pattern no match

Tags: regex, nginx

```
map $http_referer $root {
    ~^https://example.com/(?<project>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/(?<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(/.*)?    /var/www/example.com/$project/$slug;
}
```

Why doesn't this regex match if i call it with referer like this:

`https://example.com/myproject-abc-123/myslug123-asd/`

Comment: Can you confirm it works with a very generic match, something like `~(?<test>.+)`?

Comment: found my error. I accidentally override this map by any other

Answer (score 0):

I included all files with something like:

`include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

So i had a duplicated map in an other config:

```
map $http_referer $root {
    ... some other regex matching   /var/www/example.com/...;
}
```

So my first map overrides the seccond and therefore it never get's into the one defined in the question